# Dictionary to inversed dataframe.

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

I am trying to convert a dictionary like:

```
 {'@company1': 2398429348, '@company2': 2394239,  '@company3: 349234'}
```

to a dataframe. When I do this, I get the error:

```
 "ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index".
```

This isn't terribly surprising as it would be a single row dataframe. The issue is I want the inverse of this dataframe, which I have also figured out how to do, but I cannot load the dataframe before inversing due to the above error. The question then becomes, how do I load the dataframe such that the index is the Dict1.keys() with only having a single column for the number using the above styled dictionary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a Series instead:

```
a = {'@company1': 2398429348, '@company2': 2394239,  '@company3': 349234} 
df = pd.Series(a)
print(df)
```

outputs:

```
@company1    2398429348
@company2       2394239
@company3        349234
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need another `dict` with column name:

```
d = {'@company1': 2398429348, '@company2': 2394239,  '@company3': 349234} 
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':d})
print (df)
                    A
@company1  2398429348
@company2     2394239
@company3      349234
```

And solution with [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
d = {'@company1': 2398429348, '@company2': 2394239,  '@company3': 349234} 
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
print (df)
                    0
@company3      349234
@company1  2398429348
@company2     2394239
```